# Break command is not working in if condition of for loop in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks, break

I am trying to login user by fetching data from the firebase Realtime Database, but my break command is not working as once the entered username and password are matched, it still displays an Alert message that Incorrect Password or Username by logging into the user account, and it does not show this alert for the first value, and instead shows for the remaining values. I need help.!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Alert,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from "react-native";
import firebase from "../../database/firebase";
import CustomHeader from "../CustomHeader";
import { ImageBackground } from "react-native";

var categories = [];
var categories1 = [];
var categories2 = [];
var data;
// var key;
// var data;
var count = 0;
export default class SignIn extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      isLoading: false,
      menu1:[],
      menu2: [],
    };
  }

  updateInputVal = (val, prop) => {
    const state = this.state;
    state[prop] = val.trim();
    this.setState(state);
  };

  userLogin = () => {
    console.log(this.state.email);
    console.log(this.state.password);


    firebase.database().ref('users/uid/').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

      console.log("        Again");


      snapshot.forEach(function(snap) {
         const item = snap.val();
         categories1.push(item);

         const item1 = snap.key;
         categories2.push(item1);
          
          count++;
             
      });
      console.log(count);

      /// For object Values
      console.log("Values");
      this.setState( {    //PASSING VARIABLE TO STATE
        menu1 :categories1
    })
    console.log(this.state.menu1);

     /// For object Names
     console.log("Names");
      this.setState( {    //PASSING VARIABLE TO STATE
        menu2 :categories2
    })
    console.log(this.state.menu2);



  /// Use this method to login user ///
 /// With State Array ///
 
//  const name = "AlFateh";
//   for(let i =0 ; i< count; i++)
//   {
//     if(this.state.menu2[i] == name)
//     {
//       console.log(name);
//     }
//     // console.log('nothing');
//   }



   
    
      
     


    if (this.state.email === "" || this.state.password === "") {
      Alert.alert("Enter details to signin!");
    } else {

      this.setState({
        isLoading: true,
      });


      for(let i =0 ; i< count; i++)
      {
        if( this.state.password === this.state.menu1[i] && this.state.menu2[i] === this.state.email)
        {
          console.log("User logged-in successfully!");
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            email: "",
            password: "",
          });
          
          this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeApp");
          break;
          
        }
        if( this.state.menu1[i] !== this.state.password || this.state.menu2[i] !== this.state.email)
        {
          Alert.alert("Incorrect Email Or Password!")        
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,

          
         });
         
      
        }                              
             
      }
      
        
    }
  }.bind(this));
    this.empty();
  };

  empty()
      {
        categories1 = [];
        categories2 = [];
        count = 0;

      }
      

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <ImageBackground
          source={require("../../assets/yellow_bus.jpg")}
          style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
        >
          <View style={styles.preloader}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#9E9E9E" />
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      );
    }
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("../../assets/yellow_bus.jpg")}
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
      >
        <View style={{ flex: 1, position: "absolute", width: 370, top: 1 }}>
          <CustomHeader title="Sign In" navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            placeholder="Email"
            placeholderTextColor="snow"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChangeText={(val) => this.updateInputVal(val, "email")}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            placeholder="Password"
            placeholderTextColor="snow"
            value={this.state.password}
            onChangeText={(val) => this.updateInputVal(val, "password")}
            maxLength={15}
            secureTextEntry={true}
          />

          <TouchableHighlight
            style={{
              elevation: 8,
              backgroundColor: "sandybrown",
              borderRadius: 1010,
              paddingVertical: 10,
              paddingHorizontal: 1,
            }}
            onPress={() => this.userLogin()}
          >
            <Text style={styles.appButtonText}>Sign in</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>

          <Text
            style={styles.loginText}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Register")}
          >
            Don't have account? Click here to signup
          </Text>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: 35,
    paddingTop: 155,
  },
  inputStyle: {
    width: "90%",
    marginBottom: 15,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    alignSelf: "center",
    borderColor: "whitesmoke",
    fontSize: 20,
    borderRadius: 20,
    paddingVertical: 15,
    color: "snow",
    backgroundColor: "sandybrown",
  },
  loginText: {
    color: "whitesmoke",
    marginTop: 25,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  preloader: {
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    position: "absolute",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
  appButtonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: "#fff",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    alignSelf: "center",
    textTransform: "uppercase",
  },
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have multiple `this.state.menu1` and `this.state.menu2`, do those contain different `email` and `password` or possibly be empty? If yes, then your `for` loop logic is incorrect. Try the following:

```
let loggedIn = false;
for(let i =0 ; i< count; i++)
{
    if( this.state.password === this.state.menu1[i] && this.state.menu2[i] === this.state.email)
    {
      console.log("User logged-in successfully!");
      loggedIn = true;
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        email: "",
        password: "",
      });
      
      this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeApp");
      break;
      
    }             
}

if(!loggedIn)
{
    Alert.alert("Incorrect Email Or Password!")        
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,      
     });      
}
```

Note that the `if(!loggedIn)` statement is outside of the `for` loop.